# Is there a druidic version of the spell mark of justice?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

The 5th-level cleric and 4th-level paladin spell [*mark of justice*](https://www.d20srd.org/search.htm?q=mark%20of%20justice) curses the subject when the subject performs an action chosen when the spell is cast. Is there a similar spell for punishing unruly behavior available to a druid? Official preferred, but, if unavailable, third party or homebrew versions are acceptable as are *very* simple methods of adding the spell *mark of justice* to a druid's spell list.

---

#### "Why?" or "A druid doesn't need *mark of justice* to punish the unruly. A druid punishes the unruly by *eating* them"

I like cats, but my experiences with them lead me to believe (perhaps erroneously but hear me out) that few cats would take the feat [Healing *Chi*](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112022038/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/fools/20030401c) unless taking the feat were somehow incentivized. For example, a [sufficiently persuasive](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#wildEmpathy) druid capable of [communicating with a feline](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/speakWithAnimals.htm) beforehand might convince the typical [cat](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/cat.htm) to *say* it will take the feat Healing *Chi* upon being the subject of the spell [*awaken*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/awaken.htm), but the cat could, upon becoming sentient, change its mind (as cats are wont to do and, incidentally, making the cat's previous statement not *actually* a lie—I imagine cats equivocate quite a bit). A *mark of justice* spell keyed to activating if the cat picks as its next feat a feat other than Healing *Chi* would be just the thing for keeping such a suspiciously mercurial cat in line.

But druids can't cast *mark of justice* (nor *[lesser geas](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/geasLesser.htm) et al.*, which is limited to bards, sorcerers, and wizards), yet there should be a spell available to druids for enforcing such agreements.

Threatening to kill the cat if it *doesn't* take the feat upon being the subject of the spell *awaken*—and following through to make an example of it for the benefit of other cats that may be watching—is a nonstarter. Just so you know.

(Note that it's possible the cat doesn't gain a feat from the two additional Hit Dice added by the spell *awaken*, as such a cat has 2½ Hit Dice rather than 3. If that bothers you, replace in the previous explanation the cat with a serval (*Sandstorm* 194-5).)

Comment: ...druids don’t get *geas*? **The word itself comes from Celtic mythology where it was a thing done by druids!** That’s just sad.

Comment: @KRyan I know, right? I never bothered to learn much about *AD&D 2E*'s priest spheres (I played a wizard in a log-running *2E* game), but in *AD&D* clerics got the differently-named-but-the-same-spell *quest* (through their deity's generosity—they could just as easily get something else or nothing, depending on the DM's opinion of their faith) and magic-users got *geas* (if the DM made the spell available and the PC didn't fail the roll to puzzle out the spell when he encountered the spell), but the *AD&D* druid got neither. So there's precedent for it, I guess?

Comment: @KRyan Well... y'know... there's Gorgons, and then there's Medusas, so the bar for mythological accuracy is... somewhere melting away in the earth's core.

Answer (score 3):

**Easy as 1, 2, 3.**

1. Take one level of Contemplative<sup>1</sup>.
2. Select [Fate](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Fate_domain), [Mechanus](http://www.realmshelps.net/deities/domain/Mechanus), or [Retribution](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Retribution_domain) Domain.
3. Now you have [Mark of Justice](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/markOfJustice.htm) as a spell.

---

Depending on your druid's background - [Uthgar](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Uthgar) (Forgotten Realms)<sup>3</sup> could be a very valid deity choice. He has the Retribution Domain<sup>2</sup>, and his followers worship through totem animals - which is right up a druid's alley.

Note: You would also gain several other non-druid spells which are very nice. Especially since you want Mark of Justice, Speak with Dead could be very nice in application. "Hey, dead thing, who did this to you?" "She did it." "Well, she won't do that again." Shield of Faith would also possibly free up a ring (of protection) slot.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Bonus Domain: Upon adopting the contemplative class a character gains access to a bonus domain of her choice.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Domain Spells: 1st-[Shield of Faith](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/shieldOfFaith.htm); 2nd-[Bear's Endurance](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/bearsEndurance.htm); 3rd-[Speak with Dead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/speakWithDead.htm); 4th-[Fire Shield](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/fireShield.htm); 5th-[Mark of Justice](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/markOfJustice.htm); 6th-[Banishment](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/banishment.htm); 7th-[Spell Turning](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/spellTurning.htm); 8th-[Discern Location](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/discernLocation.htm); 9th-[Storm of Vengeance](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/stormOfVengeance.htm)</sub>

<sup>3</sup><sub>His clerics often multi-class as barbarians, **druids** or rangers.</sub>

Comment: While it's not official, third party, or playtested homebrew, that *is* dead easy. It's a shame to lose that sexy druid level to do something druids should be able to do anyway, though.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally No. There is not a spell by another name that druids have that mimics mark of justice. Technically, it might be hiding somewhere really obscure.

That said, there are ways to add spells outside of a spell list to a character's spell list. Categorically: most are quests unto them selves, feats, or prestige classes, but there is a lot out there. The option that might be better is researching a spell, though it takes time (Dungeon Masters Guide).

Further, depending on how strict table/GM is several 'inventive' options might be possible, such as command animal and arguing it lingers or a diplomacy/bluff check.